# How to prove client (web user) took some specific action

Tags: rest, security

This question of more from legal point of view.

In general, applications keep audit logs, to keep trail of who did what. But is that really useful in case of legal matter.

Reason for this doubt is, application itself is creating those audit logs. Yes we keep client IPs, time, userid, and action in audit log, but will that be sufficient to prove some user did exactly xyz modification in record from that IP at that time and not the application itself did that.

What exactly is considered as proof, that user actually sent this state (in REST standards) which is there in database.

Even if we store hash of input to server, that does not mean application did not change anything before calculating hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This answer does not take into account network repudiation because that is a different story altogether and not relevant to the web app itself, but rather the hosting service.

---

It all boils down to the application source code. When was the application source last compiled? And since its last compilation, has there been any incidents? Is the decompiled binary of the current application state and the last compiled application state the same. Is there any malicious code in the current application code?

But, having worked with some legal agencies, most of them do not not put in effort to search so deep unless you are involved in some high-profile case. most of the time, law enforcement will just request the application-generated logs and automatically trust it (unless the accused user sues the web app provider for falsifying logs).